# SharePoint 2010- A List is not appearing in Search result even it is crawled

Tags: sharepoint-search

I have created a new SharePoint site into my existing SharePoint Application, then i created many lists and libraries into this new site.

except one list all other Lists and Libraries of the site are appearing into SharePoint Search. As per the crawl logs this list has been crawled. I also checked this list's settings, it is set to be available for search, but i don't know why it not coming in Search results.

I waited for full crawl, even after that it is not appearing into the search result. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you are certain it was crawled you need to rule out your testing procedure. It is common for duplicate entries like "Test1, Test2, Test 3" to get removed bu duplicate checking. Ensure that your list items have unique entries.

Comment: Earlier with same name a list was present in different site within same SharePoint application, i have created that new list into the that new site by using earlier List template.When i noticed that instead of new list URL the old list URL  is coming into search results, i deleted that old list from that site so that only my new list from new site will appear into the search, but unfortunately that old list URL is still coming up into search and my new one is not showing up even it is crawled.

Comment: Have you performed a Full Crawl?

Comment: I have not manually performed it but recently it got performed automatically as per schedule, But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved.
I found that a Search Keyword has been created for this list and the Old List URL is mentioned there. I changed the URL with new list URL and saved it. My search results are fine now.

If you don't know where this search keyword can be fond, see below steps:
1) Click on site actions-> Site settings
2) Under Site Collection Administration click on option "Search Keywords".
3) Try your keyword to search here, it will show the keywords created with that search text.

Note: You should have site collection admin rights to do this.